# TypeError: The error handler must be a coroutine. sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I try to run my code and have this error , I was trying to do an error handeler on my discord py bot but it seems not working:

```
@A_lot_of_errors.error
async def error_handler(ctx , error):
    coderror = 'None'
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        coderror = 'Erreur 201'
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"❌ Permission non valide !", description = f" {ctx.author.name}, Vous devez avoir la bonne permission !\n (**Erreur {coderror}**)" , color = red ))
        print(coderror)
        return
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        coderror = '101'
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"❌ Erreur !", description = f" {ctx.author.name}, Commande introuvable !\n (**Erreur {coderror}**)" , color = red ))
        print(coderror)
        return
    if isinstance(error, commands.DisabledCommand):
        coderror = '102'
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"❌ Erreur !", description = f" {ctx.author.name}, La commande est désavctivée !\n (**Erreur {coderror}**)" , color = red ))
        print(coderror)
        return
    if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
        coderror =  'Erreur 402'
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"❌ Erreur !", description = f" {ctx.author.name}, Il y a un problème avec l'user que je ne peux définir !\n (**Erreur {coderror}**)" , color = red ))
        print(coderror)
        return
    if isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
        coderror = 'Erreur 401'
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"❌ Erreur !", description = f" {ctx.author.name}, Cette commande est réservée aux devloppeurs !\n (**Erreur {coderror}**)" , color = red ))
        print(coderror)
        return
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        coderror = 'Erreur 103'
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"❌ Erreur !", description = f" {ctx.author.name}, Merci d'attendre la fin du cooldown !\n (**Erreur {coderror}**)" , color = red ))
        print(coderror)
        return
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        coderror = 'Erreur 202'
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"❌ Erreur !", description = f" {ctx.author.name}, Erreur depuis le code source !\n (**Erreur {coderror}**)" , color = red ))
        print(coderror)
        return
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        coderror = 'Erreur 302'
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"❌ Erreur !", description = f" {ctx.author.name}, Il manque un argument !\n (**Erreur {coderror}**)" , color = red ))
        print(coderror)
        return
    else:
        coderror = '000'
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"❌ Erreur !", description = f'Erreur indeterminée: {error} \n (**{coderror}**)' , color = red ))
        print(error)
        print(coderror)
```

And the error is :  TypeError: The error handler must be a coroutine. sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command._*call*_' was never awaited

The error:

```
File "/Users/nouhame/Documents/Projects/Bot_fleur_de_cerisier.py/Python/cogs/moderation.py", line 1331, in <module>
    async def error_handler(ctx , error):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 965, in error
    raise TypeError("The error handler must be a coroutine.")
TypeError: The error handler must be a coroutine.
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
nouhame@MacBook-Pro-de-PASQUIER Bot_fleur_de_cerisier.py %
```

Comment: please post the *whole* traceback, not just a part of it.

Comment: thaks but I fidxed the problem